# Why do I have no options when my inquisitor is beside a city with a different religion?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

[image]

Is this a glitch?  I'm right beside a city with a religion that isn't my own and no options show up.

Also, unlike the other religious units, it's requiring that I have open borders with other civs to go into their territory.

Comment: The civ wikia site is immensely useful if you are not sure what a unit does: http://civilization.wikia.com .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inquisitors can't remove a religion from an opposing city.

Answer (score 0):

I also think the inquisitor has to be inside the city. So if they have another unit within the city, you have to wait.

I'm 100% allied with these AI but I still don't have the option to remove heresy.